# Cannot connect to Mysql through mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql

I want to connect python to mySQL with mySQL connector like this

```
import mysql.connector as msql
from mysql.connector import Error
user = 'user'
passw = 'pass'
host =  'host.id'
port = 1234
database = 'db-dev'

try:
conn = msql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=passw)
if conn.is_connected():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
```

but it raise error

> Error while connecting to MySQL 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on
> 'host.id:3306' (-2 Name or service not known)

I dont know whats wrong and I cant found the solution either. Thanks for help

Comment: The hostname is wrong or can not be resolved.

Comment: @KlausD. what do you mean cannot be resolved?

Comment: The DNS does not work.

Comment: @KlausD. i ran it from jupyter on web. but when i ran it locally it succeed

Comment: So, from your local machine, `host.id` is not connecting, but from web Jupyter, `host.id` is connecting.  That `host.id` might not have been exposed over the Internet or there could be other issues too.  Try doing ```telnet host.id 3306``` from the command line to make sure you are able to connect to that host. You might need to add the 'telnet' feature if it is not enabled/installed already

Comment: @Ishan I tried using ping/telnet both on my local terminal and web jupyter's terminal (ping/telnet host.id 1234). on local it connected but on web jupyter (where I try to connect python and mysql) the same error occured = 'ping: host.id: Name or service not known'. so it means the problem is the authorized access?

Comment: There is some connectivity issue only.  `host.id` is not connecting and so there is an error. Could be a firewall issue or the host.id is not resolved at all. It is resolved locally, but not from the Jupyter on web.  You can try `tracetcp` command also to see from which point onward it is not reaching out further.

Comment: @Ishan besides tracetcp, is there other solution i can try?

Comment: None that I can think of right now. `tracetcp` (needs WinPCap installed if OS is Windows) will be just like `tracert`, but on a specific port, and will give the list of all the network hops that it has to do to reach the server. Will show from which point onward, there is timeout. There might be some indication using this - whether the problem is at your end (outgoing blocked) or the other end (incoming blocked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment fellow says, the problem is in the host.
I use host

> host.id

it didn't work. Meanwhile, I use its ip instead it works.
So instead of using that form, try using its ip.